# inlineedit not working with sforce.console.openSubtab

Tags: console, inline

I have included an inline page which has inline edits in a Visualforce page.
The inline page uses `sforce.console.openSubtab`. When I comment this code inline edit on the page where it is included works fine. If I uncomment it it does not work. Is there a relation between Custom tabs and open subtabs for console?? please help.

```
  testOpenSubtab();
  function testOpenSubtab()
   {
           sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabId(openSubtab);
    }
  var openSubtab = function openSubtab(result)
  {
           var primaryTabId = result.id;
           sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId, url + '&primaryTabId=' +   primaryTabId, true, subTabName, null, true, tabId);
    };
```

***Here is the code inlinedit***

```
<apex:outputfield value="{!favExtObj.favoriteObj.Label__c}"
      rendered=" {!if((favExtObj.isLabelEditable && editable),true,false)}">
      <apex:inlineEditSupport  showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton"  
       event="ondblclick"   
       changedStyleClass="myBoldClass"  
       resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
 </apex:outputfield>
```

Comment: You might be getting a JavaScript error, look at console.

Comment: You mean to check for error message in console? Can't I check in debug log?I don't see any errors when page is displayed

Comment: It could be some JavaScript issue, so asking to check in chrome developer tools

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something is disabling inlineedit functionality. Can you post the piece of code where you use inlineedit?

Comment: I posted the code